# how to split multiline records by awk?

Tags: bash, awk

How to split multi line records by awk, i.e below file:

```
027,027,0,3,,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,1,,1.211100,1,2015-08-03,2015-07-04,,2015-11-01,0,0,2015-11-01,1,1,,0,0,0,0,0,131,0,0,0,0,0,2015-06-01,10000000000000000000,,
136,136,0,0,,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,,0.350000,1,2015-08-17,2015-07-18,,2015-11-15,0,0,2015-11-15,0,0,,0,0,0,0,0,131,0,0,0,0,0,2012-11-20,10000000000000000000,,
633,633,0,0,,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,1,,3.125300,1,2015-08-31,2015-08-01,,2015-11-29,0,0,2015-11-29,0,0,,0,0,0,0,0,131,0,0,0,0,0,2014-12-12,10000000000000000000,,
802,802,0,0,,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,1,,0.060000,1,2015-08-05,2015-07-06,,2015-11-03,0,0,2015-08-05,1,1,,0,0,0,0,0,131,0,0,0,0,0,2014-08-10,10000000000000000000,,
```

the desired output if `RS` is a `"*"` shall look like below:

```
027,027,0,3,,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,1,,1.211100,1,2015-08-03,2015-07-04,,2015-11-01,0,0,2015-11-01,1,1,,0,0,0,0,0,131,0,0,0,0,0,2015-06-01,10000000000000000000,,
********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
136,136,0,0,,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,,0.350000,1,2015-08-17,2015-07-18,,2015-11-15,0,0,2015-11-15,0,0,,0,0,0,0,0,131,0,0,0,0,0,2012-11-20,10000000000000000000,,
*******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
633,633,0,0,,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,1,,3.125300,1,2015-08-31,2015-08-01,,2015-11-29,0,0,2015-11-29,0,0,,0,0,0,0,0,131,0,0,0,0,0,2014-12-12,10000000000000000000,,
*******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
802,802,0,0,,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,1,,0.060000,1,2015-08-05,2015-07-06,,2015-11-03,0,0,2015-08-05,1,1,,0,0,0,0,0,131,0,0,0,0,0,2014-08-10,10000000000000000000,,
*******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
```

I tried to use multiple codes making `{RS="*"}` with no success.

Comment: Reference: [How to split multiline records by awk](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
$ v='\n*******************************************************************************************************************************************************************\n'
$ awk -v ORS="$v" '{print;}' file
027,027,0,3,,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,1,,1.211100,1,2015-08-03,2015-07-04,,2015-11-01,0,0,2015-11-01,1,1,,0,0,0,0,0,131,0,0,0,0,0,2015-06-01,10000000000000000000,,
*******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
136,136,0,0,,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,,0.350000,1,2015-08-17,2015-07-18,,2015-11-15,0,0,2015-11-15,0,0,,0,0,0,0,0,131,0,0,0,0,0,2012-11-20,10000000000000000000,,
*******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
633,633,0,0,,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,1,,3.125300,1,2015-08-31,2015-08-01,,2015-11-29,0,0,2015-11-29,0,0,,0,0,0,0,0,131,0,0,0,0,0,2014-12-12,10000000000000000000,,
*******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
802,802,0,0,,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,1,,0.060000,1,2015-08-05,2015-07-06,,2015-11-03,0,0,2015-08-05,1,1,,0,0,0,0,0,131,0,0,0,0,0,2014-08-10,10000000000000000000,,
*******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
```

Here is another method to achieve the same effect but without explicitly setting ORS:

```
awk '{print;} {for(i=1;i<=length($0);i++)printf "*";print"";}' file
```

Comment: @Azizieh7: Awk **ORS** is an Output equivalent of RS. Each record in the output will be printed with this delimiter.